# PHP foreach loop to populate dropdown list with values from an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an **array of an arrays** created using the following code. I'm trying to get this to loop through and populate a dropdown list.

```
$names = $db->fetchAll("select `name` from `classes`");
```

This is what is stored in the $names variable.

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Web Design ) [1] => Array ( [name] =>
>   Art History ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Gym ) [3] => Array ( [name] =>
>   English ) [4] => Array ( [name] => Biology ) [5] => Array ( [name] =>
>   3D Animation ) [6] => Array ( [name] => Tech Disc ) [7] => Array (
>   [name] => Math ) [8] => Array ( [name] => Dance ) [9] => Array (
>   [name] => Video Production ) [10] => Array ( [name] => Home Ec ) [11]
>   => Array ( [name] => Government ) [12] => Array ( [name] => Physics ) )

I have this dropdown list created and it work, but it is hand coded for each value in the array. I want to modify this so it 'loops' through all results in the array to create the dropdown.

```
<label for="per1"></label>
<select name="per1" id="per1">
    <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[0]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[0]['name'];?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[1]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[1]['name'];?></option>    
    <option value="<?php echo $names[2]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[2]['name'];?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[3]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[3]['name'];?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[4]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[4]['name'];?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[5]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[5]['name'];?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[6]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[6]['name'];?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[7]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[7]['name'];?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[8]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[8]['name'];?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[9]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[9]['name'];?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[10]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[10]['name'];?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[11]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[11]['name'];?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $names[12]['name'];?>"><?php echo $names[12]['name'];?></option>           
</select>
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**This solution works for current PHP versions.**
Simple case of using a foreach:

```
<select name="per1" id="per1">
  <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
  <?php
    foreach($names as $name) { ?>
      <option value="<?= $name['name'] ?>"><?= $name['name'] ?></option>
  <?php
    } ?>
</select>
```

**This solution works for older PHP versions.**
Simple case of using a foreach:

```
<select name="per1" id="per1">
  <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
  <?php
    foreach($names as $name) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $name['name'] ?>"><?php echo $name['name'] ?></option>
  <?php
    } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: it creates a list, but the options and values are empty. Any ideas? $names is an array of arrays. Does something have to chance because of that?

Comment: $names is an array of arrays, so when you foreach it, each 'name' is itself an array, and the array index you need is ['name']. You didn't specify a php version, but if you have a <5.4 version of PHP the short-tags I used may need to be <?php echo (instead of <?= ).

Comment: It was the <php echo because I have an older version of php. THANK YOU!

Comment: There is absolutely no benefit in mirroring the option's text as its `value` attribute -- you can safely omit the `value` declaration.  The form submission and all js processes will still work the same.  The first option will be selected if no other option is selected.

Comment: @mickmackusa that's true, but while there's no 'benefit' those aren't equivalent. My answer intended to output the same HTML. e.g. if they had `document.querySelector('#pet-select option[value=Physics]').` somewhere, it won't find that element if it's not set in the value attribute.

Comment: Okay, that's sound legit.  But if only used for element identification purposes, then you could substitute `value` for `class`, `data-value`, or maybe `id` (if guaranteed to be unique in the document).  More times than not, developers don't actually need to declare the `value` attribute and are only doing it because they copy-pasta'ed it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

i think this is enough

```
foreach($names as $key =>$value)
{?>
<option value="<?=$value['name']?>"><?=$value['name']?></option>    
<?php }
```

Comment: There is absolutely no benefit in mirroring the option's text as its `value` attribute -- you can safely omit the `value` declaration.  The form submission and all js processes will still work the same.

Comment: @mickmackusa absolutely right man, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need to write the options' `value` attributes with values that are identical to the options' text, this operation can be done with implode instead of a classic loop.

```
<?php $options = array_column($names, 'name'); ?>
<select name="per1" id="per1">
    <option value="">Choose one</option>
    <?php if ($options) {
        echo '<option>' . implode('</option><option>', $options) . '</option>';
    } ?>
</select>
```

This question is surely a mega-duplicate, but I didn't yet take the time to search for the earliest posting of this task on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Go for for each  loop to avoid these much coding.

```
<?php 
foreach($names as $nameIndex=>$nameVal){ ?>
   <option value=$nameVal['name']?>"><?=$nameVal['name']?> </option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: There is absolutely no benefit in mirroring the option's text as its `value` attribute -- you can safely omit the `value` declaration.  The form submission and all js processes will still work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Easiet way to use php array in dropdown html form or anywhere to show php foreach values in as dropdown values

```
<select name="city" required class="form-control"> 
   <option value="">Select City</option>
   <?php foreach($pkcities as $rows){ $city = $rows['city']; ?>
   <option  value="<?=$city;?>" ><?=$city;?></option>
   <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

Comment: There is absolutely no benefit in mirroring the option's text as its `value` attribute -- you can safely omit the `value` declaration.  The form submission and all js processes will still work the same.

Answer (score -1):

loop through the array [1] and get the value of the key 'name' display it in the dropdown

```
foreach($response['items'] as $key => $value)
{
   echo '<option value="'.$value['name'].'">'.$value['name'].'</option>'; 
}
```

Comment: Hello, please notice this question is more than 7 years old, and the accepted answer is very similar to your solution . Since this answer does not improve the accepted one, I'm voting to delete it.