# MySql PHP Select dropdown list

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have the following code

```
echo '<table class="bookings">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

//set variables for events
    $id = $row['CourseDateID'];
    $begin = $row['CourseStartDate'];
    $end = $row['CourseEndDate'];
    $title = $row['CourseTitle'];
    $att = $row['Attendees'];
    $venue = $row['CourseLocation'];
    $formatted = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($begin));

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $formatted . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $title . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . '<select>' . '<option>' . $att . '</option>' . '</select>' . '</td>';
    echo ' ' . '<td>' . '<a href="/cal.php?id=' . $id . '&begin=' . $begin . '&end=' . $end . '&title=' . $title . '&att=' . $att . '&venue=' . $venue . '">Add Bookings to Calendar</a>' . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
    echo '</table>';
```

I want the `<select>` to list the attendees as a dropdown but atm it creates a `<select>` box with all the attendee names in rather than a dropdown list.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: what are the contents of `$row['Attendees']`?

Comment: Yes, what is the conttents of $row['Attendees']? If that's an array, you will have to do something what's described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546818/php-foreach-loop-to-populate-dropdown-list-with-values-from-an-array-of-arrays

Comment: Sorry @FuzzyTree `$row['Attendees']` is just a grouping of `$row['Forenames']`  &  `$row['Surname']` 

Thanks

Comment: @webcreator25 instead of describing what it is, please post an example of actual contents. i.e. do `var_dump($row['Attendees'])` and post the output here

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(' ',Forenames,' ', Surname) as Attendees`
Do you mean this?! or as in show you what `$row['Attendees']` outputs?!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the attendee value is a CSV list, e.g. `John,Fred,Jane,Mary`, you have to explode that into an array and loop on it:

```
while($row = ...) {
    ... start table row+select
    $names = explode(',', $row['Attendees']);
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo "<option>$name</option>"
    }
    ... end select + table row
}
```

Comment: No joy :/ ... Attendee is a grouping of bookings forename and surname ?!

Comment: then it's a bunch of records like `date,date,conference,name`?, and each row contains ONE name? then you'll need to add a ton more logic to detect when you switch between conferences and start/end the tables/selects appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need atleast one looping structure for that, just a suggestion, jQuery is also a great way especially if you will need each id for each attendee dynamically.