# How can I iterate through a php loop and display the data in a HTML drop down form?

Tags: php, html

I have some php which lists a bunch of options (through a loop) and prints them on the page with a new line for each.

I want the options to come up in a dynamically sized drop down HTML list each with different option values.

This is the PHP (it works perfectly):

```
if($postOpts) {
    foreach($postOpts as $option)
        echo $option["name"]." - ".$option["price"]."<BR>";
}


//Otherwise, present the default postage option for domestic or international.
else {
        echo "Default Shipping Option - $".$post->getDefaultPrice();
}
```

I have a form but as you can see the form amount of options is static not dynamic:

```
<form> <!-- form action will go here --> 
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 form-label"><label>Shipping Options:</label></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="list" title="pick a type"> 
                            <!-- I assume I need to iterate through options here --> 
                            <option value="01">Shipping1</option> 
                            <option value="02">Shipping2</option> 
                            <option value="03">Shipping3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**EDIT** I forgot the other else statement in the PHP, please check.

Comment: Well have you taken a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) ? EDIT: So many answers when you try google tough..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP foreach loop to populate dropdown list with values from an array of arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546818/php-foreach-loop-to-populate-dropdown-list-with-values-from-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your select with this,

```
<select class="form-control" name="list" title="pick a type"> 
    <?php if(count($postOpts)) { ?>
       <?php foreach($postOpts as $row) { ?>
            <option value="<?= $row["price"] ?>"><?= $row["name"] ?></option> 
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
             <option value="<?= $post->getDefaultPrice() ?>"><?= "Default Shipping Option - $".$post->getDefaultPrice() ?></option> 
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: No options come up, I assume because there is no if($postOpts) in this? I can't figure out the syntax to get it in

Comment: are both things present in same page??

Comment: @bandoy123 check the answer now.

Comment: whoops, sorry it was my fault. Please check my new PHP code edit i left out the else

Comment: Check the answer now.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/Page2-ShippingOptions.php on line 67

Comment: this is line 67     <?php } else { ?>

Comment: `if` was not closed. Try now.

Comment: Sorry, php tag is not opened properly just after the `<select>`, please check that

Comment: No options are populating the list.

Comment: Even else is not coming??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93653/discussion-between-bandoy123-and-niranjan-n-raju).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    <form> <!-- form action will go here --> 
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 form-label"><label>Shipping Options:</label></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
                    <select class="form-control" name="list" title="pick a type"> 
                        <option value="">Choose type</option>
                        <?php foreach($postOpts as $option) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $option['name'].' - '.$option['price'];?>"><?php echo $option["name"]." - ".$option["price"]; ?></option> 
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: No options come up, I assume because there is no if($postOpts) in this? I can't figure out the syntax to get it in

Comment: OOPS, please check the edit I made, I forgot the else clause