# Adding php variable to dropdown menu (in Flask)

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, populate, dropdown

I originally had this script to populate a dropdown menu with query results:

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["data_id"])) {
    $query ="SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name";
    $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
    <option value="">Select Parameter</option>
<?php
    foreach($results as $col) {
?>
    <option value=""><?= $col ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
```

However the entry was always empty. I checked if this was a php syntax problem using both `<?=` and `<?php echo` as suggested in [Populating dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546818/php-foreach-loop-to-populate-dropdown-list-with-values-from-an-array-of-arrays)

No luck. So next I checked if there actually is something in my query result so I simple replaced the dropdown entry with a string variable:

```
<?php
$varName= 'testingList';
?>
    <option value=""><?= $varName ?></option>
```

Again I tried both syntax options but still no luck (i.e. testingList does not show up in the dropdown). Instead, I get a new blank dropdown option i.e. 1 empty entry is added. (PS. the value assigned will also be the same variable but I'm leaving it out at the moment to make sure its not an issue - so just focusing on getting a variable name in the dropdown menu).

Currently running PHP 5.5.9 on a remote server; the issue is also local. Any ideas greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### UPDATE

When I run the .php file independently, works just fine. But not in the flask environment so I thought I'll add the fact that I'm working in Flask.

Comment: you does not echo the key in option value. <option value=""><?= $col['key']; ?></option>

Comment: use echo "<option value=' ".$varName." '>".$col['column_name']."</option>"

Comment: your example outputs correct html: http://ideone.com/emgcTO

Comment: Correct. @Yuri Tkachenko

Comment: Hmm it does. Must be something with the server and local host I guess?

Comment: When I use the code: `<option value="">1</option>
<?php
echo '<option value="">Select Parameter</option>';
?>` only "1" is printed and an entry is not added for the echoed one. i.e. not even a blank entry.

Comment: @dter any framework you use? Can you show your PHP version?

Comment: Managed to fix this by switching to the flask framework. Basically I did everything in flask without php :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by switching everything to flask. Since this was a multiple dropdown menu, i.e. the value selected in the first dropdown populates the second dropdown, I sent the selected value from the first dropdown back to flask through Ajax, and populated the second dropdown using flask!

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the `Field` from `$col`, Try this:

```
<option value=""><?= $col['Field'] ?></option>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. But I'm sure its not because of the syntax since even a simple example/variable doesn't get printed out.